# Having trouble mounting CDs (even music CDs) - Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: mount, cd

Seems like my CD reader is bricked.
This is bizarre, since "eject" and "wodim" (or the GUI equivallent) function: I am able to eject a CD and I am able to burn a CD-R - can't check though as it does not read any CD.

```
> sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom 
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

> sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom -o ro -t iso9660
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (could this be the IDE device where you in fact use
   ide-scsi so that sr0 or sda or so is needed?)
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so

> dmesg
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Add. Sense: Logical block address out of range
sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 01 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 64
isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16
```

I am certain the filesystem is iso9660 (I have an iso copy of this CD as a file and I can mount it as a loop device).

I tried to mount an audio CD, it yields the same errors (same with VLC).

I don't understand what's up with my system.

Any way I can diagnose the problem ?
Fix it ?
Has anybody seen similar behaviour before ?

I would love to hear from you.

Comment: Can you give the output of `dmesg | tail`, please?

Comment: Done, edited.
I created two CDs, one with wodim, the other with the standard GUI CD Creator (on a Gnome system).
I tried both CDs on a Windows machine. One shows content (I thin the GUI created one), the other seems empty (blank).
I tried on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine again after a reboot and both CDs are viewed as blanks and can now listen to the audio CD (albeit with lots of errors of the type `main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late, increasing pts_delay to`...). I believe something got corrupted and neither session got closed at the end of the creation.

Comment: Normal CDs ord DVDs work? So the bought ones?

Comment: Tried another method for finalising the disk, this method did not work, so started again with fresh CDs. It now works. I think my OS was in a weird state and something was corrupted along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System was buggy.

Solved after reboot.